# published book based on dissertation

Tags: copyright

I published a book based on my dissertation with an academic publisher. The book was essentially rewritten. Can I publish the dissertation itself or is does the publisher have rights to it, as well?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by: “The book was essentially rewritten”? Anyway, the answer depends only on what kind of copyright agreement you signed with the publisher.

Comment: Could you also specify your discipline, roughly speaking? (is this medieval history, biochemistry, ethnography, ... ?)

Comment: When you graduated did you file a copyright notice?  Also, is there NO overlapping text between your book and dissertation?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think I understand.  You started with a dissertation.  You wanted to turn it into a publication, so (as is most often the case for dissertations that are not themselves previously published papers stapled together) you did a substantial amount of rewriting, after which you were -- congratulations! -- able to publish it is a book.  Now you want to publish the un-reworked thesis separately?  Why?!?

If there is a lot of material in your dissertation that didn't make it into your book, then -- after suitable reworking, presumably -- you can aim for a further publication.  If not; I don't see what you're trying to accomplish by publishing a worse version after publishing a better version.  I don't think that "publication rights" should even enter into the discussion until this has been addressed.

Comment: Pete, I wonder if this may be something where norms/expectations vary between fields. I've asked the OP to clarify this

Comment: @Yemon: As almost always, it would be very helpful to know the academic field, yes.  I don't know of any academic field in which this practice is standard or sensible...but maybe I'm about to learn.

Comment: My impression is that in the humanities, publishing a book directly based on the dissertation is more common, and perhaps the workflow for doing so is different from e.g. math(s)